# Find α (Triangles)

Tags: geometry, triangles

Find $\alpha$ if $A = 4\alpha$.

[image: triangle_with_altitude]

Can someone explain to me how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, you should include information on the source of the problem, include any work you have done, and explain why you are stuck so that we can write a response appropriate to your skill level.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig - Which program did you use to sketch the diagram? :)

Comment: I used the LaTeX drawing program tikz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know $A \hat{D}C = 90 \unicode{xb0}$ and we are given that $\hat{A}= 4 \alpha$.

Now, in triangle $ADC$, we require $$ 4\alpha + \alpha + 90\unicode{xb0}= 180 \unicode{xb0} \\ \therefore 5\alpha + 90 \unicode{xb0} = 180 \unicode{xb0}$$

All that is left now, is to solve for $\alpha$

\begin{align} 5\alpha &= 180 \unicode{xb0} - 90 \unicode{xb0}\\ \therefore5\alpha &= 90 \unicode{xb0} \\ \therefore \alpha &= 18 \unicode{xb0}\end{align}